# How to extract element of pandas list column specified in other column?

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with two columns:

- col1: a list column
- col2: an integer that specifies the index of the list element that I would like to extract and store in col3. It can take `NaN` value, in which case the outcome should be `NaN` as well.

Sample input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1' : [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D', 'E'], ['F', 'G']], 
    'col2' : [0, 2, np.nan]})
```

Expected output:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1' : [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D', 'E'], ['F', 'G']], 
    'col2' : [0, 2, np.nan],
    'col3' : ['A', 'E', np.nan]})
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use a basic apply:

```
def func(row):
    if np.isnan(row.col2):
        return np.nan
    else:
        return row.col1[int(row.col2)]


df['col3'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

output:

```
        col1  col2 col3
0     [A, B]   0.0    A
1  [C, D, E]   2.0    E
2     [F, G]   NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a list comprehension to compare the two columns too.

```
df['col3'] = [i[int(j)] if not np.isnan(j) else j for i,j in zip(df.col1,df.col2)]

        col1  col2 col3
0     [A, B]   0.0    A
1  [C, D, E]   2.0    E
2     [F, G]   NaN  NaN
```